# php replace specific words in a description with uppercase words and loop through it

Tags: php, string, foreach, str-replace

Need to replace ALL present words within a string that tested against an array with the uppercase search words.

I am stuck with the right loop now.

My code:

```
   $array = [
        'weizen',
        'dinkel',
        'gerste',
        'khorasan',
        'eier',
        'haselnuss',
        'walnuss'];

   $description = "Weizenbrötchen auf Hartweizenbasis und Eiern mit Walnusscreme und Haselnusspaste sind leckerer mit Dinkelflocken."

foreach($array as $item) {
if (strpos($description, $item) !== false) {
   // $description;
 echo 
 str_replace($item, mb_strtoupper($item), $description);   
}
}
```

**Actual outcome:**
"WEIZENbrötchen auf Hartweizenbasis und Eiern mit Walnusscreme und Haselnusspaste sind leckerer mit Dinkelflocken.Weizenbrötchen auf Hartweizenbasis und EIERn mit Walnusscreme und Haselnusspaste sind leckerer mit Dinkelflocken.Weizenbrötchen auf Hartweizenbasis und Eiern mit WALNUSScreme und Haselnusspaste sind leckerer mit Dinkelflocken.Weizenbrötchen auf Hartweizenbasis und Eiern mit Walnusscreme und HASELNUSSpaste sind leckerer mit Dinkelflocken.Weizenbrötchen auf Hartweizenbasis und Eiern mit Walnusscreme und Haselnusspaste sind leckerer mit DINKELflocken.

**Desired outcome:**

WEIZENbrötchen auf HartWEIZENbasis und EIERn mit WALNUSScreme und HASELNUSSpaste sind leckerer mit DINKELflocken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to make a regex out of the strings to be replaced, and then use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to convert any matched values to upper case:

```
$array = [
        'weizen',
        'dinkel',
        'gerste',
        'khorasan',
        'eier',
        'haselnuss',
        'walnuss'];

$description = "Weizenbrötchen auf Hartweizenbasis und Eiern mit Walnusscreme und Haselnusspaste sind leckerer mit Dinkelflocken.";

$pattern = '/' . implode('|', $array) . '/iu';
echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) { return mb_strtoupper($m[0]); }, $description);
```

Output:

```
WEIZENbrötchen auf HartWEIZENbasis und EIERn mit WALNUSScreme und HASELNUSSpaste sind leckerer mit DINKELflocken.
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/bqHai)

Answer (score 1):

Using `array_map` to convert your original array to uppercase and also to prepare patterns, then use `preg_replace` to do it:

```
$array = [
        'weizen',
        'dinkel',
        'gerste',
        'khorasan',
        'eier',
        'haselnuss',
        'walnuss'];

  $description = "Weizenbrötchen auf Hartweizenbasis und Eiern mit Walnusscreme und Haselnusspaste sind leckerer mit Dinkelflocken.";

  $replaces = array_map(function($v){ return strtoupper($v);}, $array);
  $patterns = array_map(function($v){ return '/'.$v.'/i';},$array);

  $str = preg_replace($patterns,$replaces,$description);

  echo $str;
```